# Javascript key events order of execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following Javascript code (with jQuery) on my web page -- the user types into a text field and the application does one thing if there's a value in the field and something else if the field is empty (because the user was pressing the delete or backspace key). The code that I have looks like this:

```
$('input#textInput').keyup( function(event) {
    if($(this).val()) {
        console.log('non-empty string in the text field');
    }
    else {
        console.log('no text in the text field');
    }
}
```

The problem is that it looks like the callback function executes before the character appears in the text field. So if the field is empty and I press the <kbd>p</kbd> key, what seems to occur is the `keydown`, `keypress`, and `keyup` events are generated, the `keyup` callback function gets executed and 'no text in the text field' gets logged, and then the 'p' character appears in the text field, which isn't what I want.

Does anyone know how I can execute a callback on any of the key events and access the value that would appear in the text field?

Comment: The "keypress" event fires after the value is updated, I think. *edit* oops no it doesn't

Comment: "the keyup callback function gets executed and 'no text in the text field' gets logged" - I tried multiple time and for keyup it printed "non-empty string in the text field". http://jsfiddle.net/skram/uH4H3/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could set a timeout:

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var inp = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(inp.value);
  }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input` event should do roughly what you want.  It fires after the value changes and is supported on most modern browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input